# Bootstrap navbar distortion on narrow viewport

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. I have made a navbar, but it gets distorted on narrow viewport (works well on ipad mini, but distorts on phone). On mobile phone, the navbar is broken such that each element of the navbar is present in a separate row; which is undesirable. I want the entire navbar to be present in one row only. I have attached my code below. Kindly suggest a solution to the above mentioned problem.

```
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jaldi' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/home/css/base.css">
</head>
<title>My Project</title>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"></nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">        
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My Project</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-center">
            <li>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left navbar-input-group" role="search" method="POST" action="/question/add/">{% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="searchbox" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a question" name="question">
                    </div>
                    {{ question_form }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default hidden-xs">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">{{ user.first_name }}
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/userprofile/{{ user.get_username }}/show/">Profile</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="/account/logout/">Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<br>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Comment: One error I see is that you have two
`<nav class="navbar navbar-default"></nav>`

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your rendered HTML (and any CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you want your whole navbar in a single row, you should put it inside a `<div class="row"></div>` tag.